# SSRS line chart not connecting data points

Tags: join, reporting-services, graph, charts, line

I've looked high and low and can't seem to find an answer to what appears to be quite a straightforward issues (I would think).

I have a line chart where there is data at several points in a series but only only one set of points link up.

Does anyone know why this is? Is it to do with my data? If it is, I am struggling to see any relationships in the data that may explain this behavior.

Here is what I mean:

[image: Messed up data points]

As you can see, the red diamonds should be connecting - the same could be said about the blue squares and the dark blue triangles. Any thoughts?

Apologies if my colors are wrong - I'm colorblind.

Answer (score 16):

Okay, so I worked this out.

Firstly, in order to get the lines to join up, you need to set the `EmptyPoint` colour for the series.

1. select your series in your chart
2. In the properties tab (not the dialog) drill down into the EmptyPoint property and set the colour to be Black

This will get them joining up - yay! But part of the line is colour and the other part is black, right? That's a bit silly, especially considering if you leave the colour to Automatic on the EmptyPoint that it will be transparent.

So, then we need to get the series and the EmptyPoint's colours in sync.
Using code from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239350.aspx). I added some code to the code of the report.

1). Right click on an empty space on the report and select "Report Properties"
 2). In the code tab, paste the following:

```
Private colorPalette As String() = {"#418CF0", "#FCB441", "#E0400A", "#05642E", "#1A3B69", "#BFBFBF", "#E0400A", "#FCB441", "DarkBlue", "Tomato", "Orange", "CornflowerBlue", "Gold", "Red", "Green", "LightBlue", "Lime", "Maroon", "LightSteelBlue", "Tan", "Silver"}
Private count As Integer = 0
Private mapping As New System.Collections.Hashtable()

    Public Function GetColor(ByVal groupingValue As String) As String

        If mapping.ContainsKey(groupingValue) Then
                Return mapping(groupingValue)
        End If

        Dim c As String = colorPalette(count Mod colorPalette.Length)
            count = count + 1
            mapping.Add(groupingValue, c)
            Return c
    End Function
```

Then we need to call this code when setting the colour of the series and of the `EmptyPoint`.

1. Select your series
2. In the properties tab paste something the following (replace *WhateverTheGroupIsForYourSeries* with your series group name): `=Code.GetColor(Fields!*WhateverTheGroupIsForYourSeries*.Value)`
3. Drill down to the color element of the `EmptyPoint` Series property
4. Paste the same text as from point two [e.g. `=Code.GetColor(Fields!*WhateverTheGroupIsForYourSeries*.Value)`]

And voila! You're done!
I can't believe how unnecessarily difficult this is :D

Comment: Everything worked fine until i tried steps 2 and 4. The problem is with accessing the GetColor function. It seems like Code written in the report properties that define the GetColor function is not accessible here in the color element. Any idea how to resolve this. I am using RDLC and not the RDL which is on the reporting services.

Comment: Figured out my mistake! The series name i provided had a typo. You solution worked. Thanks. The only problem i see now is that the legends color are messed up. There are more than one appearence of same color.

Comment: I was using CountRows() for my Y Value, which gave me the illusion of Empty Points, but were actual points with a value of zero.  To get around that, I changed my Y Value to

    =IIF(CountRows() > 0, CountRows(), Nothing)

Comment: Your answer is very useful and pointed me to the right direction. However I decided to deliver the line colors with my data and applied the fields to the line color as well as toe the empty point color and so I have full control, could avoid the code approach and have me legend lined up with the line colors.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a problem where it was showing markers but not the lines. I ended up solving it by wrapping the expression in a CInt() to convert it to an integer.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more with a code example?  I'm interested in trying this solution.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me.  Choose the chart values field, click the arrow and choose Expression, and then wrap whatever is in there with CINT([your expression]).  Thank you SteveCav

Comment: Just tried that, would have been nice, but that just sends all the null-Values to 0. So it connects the dots, but with other dots that are at 0 and not the next dot

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this is to do a recursive select (if you have very large data sets don't do this, it kills performance). So you could make your dataset:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Store order by Date desc) as rn
FROM StorePerformance
```

Now you can have your category group be rn (it should group by rn and sort by rn) but select date for its label.  This will still display the date on your x axis, but since you are grouping by rn the data will still be continuous and all of the lines will connect. Also your legend will still match.

I still haven't looked deeply into how much this shifts the data points since we are plotting with row number and displaying date, but if you are mainly concerned with visualizing trends in the lines and aren't as concerned with where they are at a given point in time in relation to one another, it will serve you just fine.  Otherwise I would leave the chart the way it is and just read the plot points, which are still valid data.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Nyx.png)

Just put your Fields!(YourSeriesGroup).Value in Series Groups to above of 
Fields!(YourCategoryGroup).Value in Category Groups, your series group should be in both Series Groups and Category Groups (should be above of your initial category group).

And after that right click horizontal axis and select Horizontal Axis Properties. Set Axis Type to Scalar and click OK.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfZh6.png)